# XSL Displaying a message to the user if an element's count is 0

Tags: html, xml, xslt, web, xsd

I have an element called channels which has been given values in the XML files. what i want to do is that when the XML file doesn't have any channel , display a message to the user.
here is my code.

```
    <h2>Channels Subscription:</h2>
    <xsl:template>
    <xsl:if test="  <xsl:value-of select="count(subscription/channels)"/>
 ==0)">
 <p>You have no channels</p>
    </xsl:if>

        </xsl:template>
```

the code above doesn't work 
after that comes the other part wich is table.. when a user has a channel or more it gets displayed

```
<xsl:for-each select="subscription/channels">

    <xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="@favourite='true'">


                <h3 >Channel Name:</h3> <h3 style="color:green;"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></h3>

                </xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <h3 >Channel Name: </h3><h3 style="color:black; "><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></h3>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
                    <p>ID: <xsl:value-of select="@id"/></p>
                    <h3>Programs:</h3>
                    <xsl:for-each select="programs">
    <table ID="gradient-style">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Program Name:</th>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Broadcast Time:</th>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@broadcastFrequency"/> at <xsl:value-of select="@broadcastTime"/> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Description:</th>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>    
        </xsl:for-each>
```

and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `xsl:if` is wrong, it should be like

```
<xsl:if test="count(subscription/channels) = 0">
   <p>You have no channels</p>
</xsl:if>
```

For reference: [http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl%3aif](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl%3Aif)